# If A and B are co-primes, does Ax mod B (where x, any positive int) gives {0,1,2,....,B-1}?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If $A$ and $B$ are co-primes (i.e. $\gcd(A,B)=1$), does $A\cdot x \bmod B$ (where $x\in \mathbb N$) give as result an element of $\{0,1,2,....,B-1\}$ ?

Comment: Are you asking whether every element in the set can be reached given appropriate $x$ (e.g. this function is surjective) or are you "just" asking whether the result will _always_ be in this set (without additional properties)? (I've also edited your post to look fancier, if you don't like any changes feel free to edit again)

Comment: Yes, I am asking whether the result will always be in this set or not !!!?

Answer (score 6):

**Claim:** If $A$ and $B$ are coprime, the map
$$\begin{align*}
\{0,\dots,B-1\}\ &\to\ \{0,\dots,B-1\}
,\\
x \ &\mapsto\  A\cdot x\bmod B
\end{align*}$$
is a well-defined bijection.

It is clear directly from the definition of $\bmod$ that $A\cdot x\bmod B$ is indeed between $0$ and $B-1$.
Surjectivity follows, e.g., from [Bézout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).
Any surjection between finite sets of the same cardinality is automatically bijective.

In particular, this implies that the map
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb Z\ &\to\ \{0,\dots,B-1\}
,\\
x \ &\mapsto\  A\cdot x\bmod B
\end{align*}$$
is also surjective.